# Printing Empty Array

Tags: java

When I add a new trip in the program, and choose to print all trips it outputs an empty information, but the index number is correct

### when i add two trips :

**what i'm expected:**

```
Name: customer name
mobile numer : the number

Name: customer name2
mobile numer : the number2
```

**what it outputs:**

```
Name: 
mobile numer : 

Name: 
mobile numer :
```

**that's my code**

```
import java.util.*;
class Trip {

    private static String customerName;
    private static String mobileNo;
    private static String reservationCode;
    public static int totalReservations;
    public static Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    public Trip(){//The constructer
        customerName = " ";
        mobileNo = " ";
    }

    public Trip(String Name, String MobileNo) {
        customerName=Name;
        mobileNo=MobileNo;
    }

    public void setcustomerName(String Name){
        customerName = Name;
    }

    public void setmobileNo(String MobileNo){
        mobileNo = MobileNo;
    }

    public String getcustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public String getmobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public static void printTripInfo(){

        Trip M=new Trip();
        M.getcustomerName();
        M.getmobileNo();

        System.out.println("Customer Name:"+customerName);
        System.out.println("Phone Number:"+mobileNo);

    }

}//end class trip


public class CabCompany{
    private static int reservations_size=20;
    private static Trip[] trip;
    Trip NewTrip;
    public static int user;

    //the scanners
    public static Scanner textinput=new Scanner (System.in);
    public static Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[]args){
        trip=new Trip[reservations_size];

        do {
            System.out.println("1. Add a new trip\n2. Find a trip by reservation code\n3. List all trips\n");
            user=input.nextInt();

            if ( user == 1) {
                System.out.println("Name:");
                String Name = textinput.nextLine();

                System.out.println("MobileNo:");
                String MobileNo = input.next();

                boolean flag;
                CabCompany Y = new CabCompany();
                flag = Y.addTrip(Name,MobileNo);

                if( flag == true ) {
                    System.out.println("the trip has been added successfully");

                } else if ( flag == false ){
                    System.out.println("the trip hasn't been added");
                }
            }

            if( user == 2) {
                printAll();
            }

            if( user == 3 ){
                System.out.println("The total Reservations is:"+Trip.totalReservations);
            }

        } while (user != 7);
    }


    public boolean addTrip(String customerName,String mobileNo){

        boolean flag = true;

        if ((mobileNo.length() == 10))
        {


            NewTrip=new Trip(customerName, mobileNo);
            Trip.totalReservations++;
            int i = Trip.totalReservations - 1;
            trip[i] = NewTrip;


            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    public static void printAll() {

        for(int t=0; t<Trip.totalReservations; t++){
            trip[t].printTripInfo();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've presented a *lot* of code here. Please reduce this to a [mcve]. But I would strongly advise you to: a) start following Java naming conventions; b) reconsider making all your `Trip` fields static. Do you understand what `static` means? I suspect that may be where the problem is...

Comment: Please take you a favour and learn how to use the debugger. The sooner the better.

Comment: well, i did and make them all static but there's another problem which is print only the last array information , that's why i made them non-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void printAll() {
    for(int t=0; t<Trip.totalReservations; t++){
        trip[t].printTripInfo();
    }
}
```

Here, you are calling `printTripInfo()` method on each instance of the array, but you are not using the instance. Instead you are creating new instance of `Trip` everytime you are calling the `printTripInfo()` method.
So you will need to change your method

```
public static void printTripInfo(){
    Trip M=new Trip();
    M.getcustomerName();
    M.getmobileNo();
    System.out.println("Customer Name:"+customerName);
    System.out.println("Phone Number:"+mobileNo);
}
```

to

```
public void printTripInfo(){
    System.out.println("Customer Name:"+ this.getcustomerName());
    System.out.println("Phone Number:"+ this.getmobileNo());
}
```

But when you will try to run the code with above change, it simply won't compile. Because you are trying to access static fields `customerName` and `mobileNo` from non-static method. So you will also need to change your `customerName` and `mobileNo` fields to non-static ones.

Comment: thanks man!!!!! good explanation!!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is many things to say. I will try to concentrate on the essential.

Use a single scanner and replace :

```
     System.out.println("Name:");
     String Name = textinput.nextLine();

     System.out.println("MobileNo:");
     String MobileNo = input.next();
```

by :

```
     System.out.println("Name:");
     String Name = textinput.nextLine();

     System.out.println("MobileNo:");
     String MobileNo = textinput.nextLine();
```

Using two scanners is error prone and I use only `nextLine()` because `next()` and `nextLine()` should not be mixed with a same scanner to  prevent some side-effect when we mix them.

In the`printTripInfo()` method, make the method not static and remove the `Trip` instance you declare and since you is already in the context of a Trip instance when you invoke the method here :

```
   for(int t=0; t<Trip.totalReservations; t++){
        trip[t].printTripInfo();
    }
```

`trip` is a array of `Trip` instances.

You write that :

```
public static void printTripInfo(){
    Trip M=new Trip();
    M.getcustomerName();
    M.getmobileNo();

    System.out.println("Customer Name:"+customerName);
    System.out.println("Phone Number:"+mobileNo);
}
```

You should write that :

```
public void printTripInfo(){
    System.out.println("Customer Name:"+customerName);
    System.out.println("Phone Number:"+mobileNo);
 }
```

Comment: MAN IT WORKED!!! thanks!!!! , but it didn't change the scanners because i had to

Comment: great :) you are welcome

Comment: He also needs to change his static fields `customerName` and `mobileNo` to non-static ones, otherwise when he will try to add multiple entries, his older entries in the array will get change. So at the end he will get all entries with same `customerName` and `mobileNo` values..

Comment: Of course. I forgot to mention it.